# Flutter app for Android with pay plugin don't compile

Tags: android, flutter, android-pay

After adding pay (1.0.7) library to my flutter app, it stoped to compile for Android (api 30).
To make a quick test, I created empty counter app using newest flutter version and only added pay 1.0.7. From that moment app stop to compile and I get an errors:

```
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
e: ../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/pay_android-1.0.6/android/src/main/kotlin/io/flutter/plugins/pay_android/GooglePayHandler.kt: (172, 27): Expecting a parameter declaration
e: ../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/pay_android-1.0.6/android/src/main/kotlin/io/flutter/plugins/pay_android/PayMethodCallHandler.kt: (40, 28): Expecting a parameter declaration
e: ../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/pay_android-1.0.6/android/src/main/kotlin/io/flutter/plugins/pay_android/PayMethodCallHandler.kt: (56, 52): Expecting a parameter declaration
e: ../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/pay_android-1.0.6/android/src/main/kotlin/io/flutter/plugins/pay_android/PayPlugin.kt: (41, 79): Expecting a parameter declaration
e: ../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/pay_android-1.0.6/android/src/main/kotlin/io/flutter/plugins/pay_android/PayPlugin.kt: (55, 67): Expecting a parameter declaration
...
```

The same happens after doing all instructions in readme. Error appears when I change minSdkVersion to 19 - because this is a requirement and before change it also not compile but with message about to low sdk.

The same apps (mine and starter counter app) perfectly run on iOS (emulator/device).

How to solve it ?

Answer (score 0):

Thankfully this was an easy fix. You can see the original [fix here](https://www.giters.com/google-pay/flutter-plugin/issues/107) and it was raised as an issue ([#117](https://github.com/google-pay/flutter-plugin/issues/117)) just last month.

In `android/app/build.gradle`:

```
// minSdkVersion flutter.minSdkVersion
minSdkVersion 19
```

Then in `android/build.gradle`

```
// ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.50'
ext.kotlin_version = '1.4.20'


// classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0'
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.1'
```